# Change the default date of the current inline jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default date of an already rendered inline datepicker?  I have set up a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/xf0qc41k/
I currently destroy the datepicker and re-render it with a new default date if I want the default date to change. This works fine but I wondered if it is possible to change the current inline datepicker's default date on the fly.

HTML:

```
<div class="inline_datepicker"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.inline_datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: "2014-10-21",
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `setDate`:

```
$('.inline_datepicker').datepicker('setDate', "2014-12-25");
```

Comment: Looks like Christmas came early! Thank you very much!